# Best way to show user info in zend layout

Tags: zend-framework, zend-layout

I'm trying to show information about user in my Zend Framework application. I'm using one layout script for all controllers (except login controller). And now I want to show information about logged in user (this layout is used only on controllers with logged in users).

I want to separate logic of retrieving user information into some object and view script that will render information. So that in future I could change one of these parts independently.

So the question is what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using an action helper for this purpose. You can retrieve the user information and add it to the view. Something like that:

```
class My_LayoutHelper extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {
    /**
     * Predispatch hook.
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $view = $this->getActionController()->view;

        // Get the user data from wherever you have them
        $userInfo = getUserInfo();

        // Inject it into the view
        $view->username = $userInfo->name;
    }
}
```

And in the layout script, you can write

```
<?php echo $this->username; ?>
```

wherever you need to.

More information on action helpers here: http://devzone.zend.com/article/3350

Hope that helps...